# Postgres call function/procedure which executes query & then deletes

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm looking for a way to have a function or procedure in Postgresql 12, which can be called with a single line for usage in commandline.

1) Perform a query that takes a parameter as input

For example:
    `select id from table1 where name =  $PARAMETER`

2) Based on the ids returned, execute multiple deletes

For example:

```
delete from table2 where id = $id
delete from table3 where id = $id
```

In SQL Server I would use a stored procedure for this, but I'm lost on how how to do this in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Postgres also has the concept of stored procedures and functions.  If you can write them in SQL Server you shouldn't have much problem adapting to the plpgsql syntax.

Comment: @steiner: that is completely incorrect. That's completely different compared to sql server.

Comment: I'm not saying the syntax is exactly the same.  I'm saying with some research and reading you should be able to adapt it.

Answer (score 1):

If your origin is on MS SQL, then good start is reading [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html). The language and environment is different (maybe very different to what you know).

But your task is simple - you can use procedures (from Postgres 11) or functions:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION s(_name text)
RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE _id int;
BEGIN
  SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE name = _name INTO _id;
  DELETE FROM table2 WHERE id = _id;
  DELETE FROM table2 WHERE id = _id;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

or like procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE s(_name text)
AS $$
DECLARE _id int;
BEGIN
  SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE name = _name INTO _id;
  DELETE FROM table2 WHERE id = _id;
  DELETE FROM table2 WHERE id = _id;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Function is executed via `SELECT s('somename')`

Procedure is executed by statement `CALL s('somename')`